# gatsbyjsプロジェクトをRekit Studioを導入しようとしてnpmがエラーを返す件

Tags: npm

1.gatsby newでプロジェクトを作成
2.npm install rekit -g
3.rekit create my-app -clean
で下のようなエラーがでました。
助けてくださいお願いしますm(_)m

エラー内容
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:605
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'undefined/package.json'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:603:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at loadPlugins (/Users/takezakiyuuta/ReactDirestory/workspace/developtest/node_modules/rekit-core/core/plugin.js:48:22)
    at Object.getPlugins (/Users/takezakiyuuta/ReactDirestory/workspace/developtest/node_modules/rekit-core/core/plugin.js:15:5)
    at Object. (/Users/takezakiyuuta/.nvm/versions/node/v11.5.0/lib/node_modules/rekit/bin/rekit.js:185:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:721:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:732:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)

Answer (score 0):

すみません。解決しました。
yarn でrekit-coreとrekit-studioをインストールしたのちcreteできました。
お騒がせしました。
閲覧ありがとうございました。